# Some(the) washing

Tags: difference, determiners, quantifiers

What is the difference?

> 1. I need to do **some washing**.
> 2. I need to do **the washing**.

Can I also use "I need to do some washing" to refer to washing veggies before cooking a meal?

Comment: I'm going to wash the veggies before cooking them. - how about saying it like that?

Answer (score 1):

*Some washing* means you are going to do part of whatever "washing" means.  This implies you might not wash everything that is needed.

*The washing* means you are going to address all of whatever "washing" means.

But saying "washing" in this way usually refers to laundry or washing a big thing like a car.  You should just say this:

> I need to wash the veggies.

Unless there is a lot of veggies or you are the one washing veggies as part of a team.

Answer (score 0):

The term [washing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/washing) is a noun: in this context would most likely be taken to mean "A quantity of clothes, bed linen, etc. that is to be washed or has just been washed."

There is no real difference between **do some washing** and **do the washing**: they both mean washing clothes, linen etc.

if you want to talk about washing vegetables, you would have to use the verb [wash](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wash), where the relevant meaning would be "clean with water".

> I need to wash the vegetables

Alternatively, you could use the verbal noun (gerundive) form of the verb like this:

> The vegetables need washing.